# SwiftUI Gradient Polyline on Map View

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, gradient, polyline

According to this WWDC video gradient Polylines should be available in SwiftUI map views.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/?time=1360

```
let coordinates = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.3352, longitude: -122.0322),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0522, longitude: -118.2437)
    ]

    let gradient = LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .green, .blue], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)

    let stroke = StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, dash: [10, 10])

    var body: some View {
        Map {
            MapPolyline(coordinates: coordinates)
                .stroke(gradient, style: stroke)
            
        }
    }
```

Seems to render the whole polyline with the first colour in the given colours for the gradient. Is this a bug/is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close! It works if you stroke the polyline using a simple `Gradient`, instead of a `LinearGradient`.

A `Gradient` can be created using an array of colors or color stops:

```swift
let gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red, .green, .blue])

// all other code unchanged
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Their is no Api for now, but we can create ourselves, I wrote an example, hopefully can help you.

**Solution Path**:
https://github.com/OAK-WJR/SwiftUI-ProblemSolutions.git

**Thoughts**:
Create a custom `UIViewRepresentable` to embed `MKMapView` into the SwiftUI view, and use custom `MKOverlay` and `MKOverlayRenderer` to achieve the gradient effect

1: Create a gradient polygon overlay

2: Create a gradient polygon renderer

3: Embed MKMapView in SwiftUI

**Results Display:**
[image]